# can't get child records of parent class in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using mysql as the backend db with EntityFrameworkCore in my repository. Each user should have related records in another table for when they last logged in. 
 When I try to load my list of users all of them come back with no matching records.  Not sure why.

Method getting users:

```
public IEnumerable<UserItem> GetUsers(Func<User, bool> query, int count, int skip)
{
    var users = new List<UserItem>();
    foreach (var user in context.User.Where(query).Skip(skip).Take(count))
    {
        users.Add(new UserItem()
        {
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastLoginDate = user.UserLoginLog.Any()? user.UserLoginLog.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateLogged).FirstOrDefault().DateLogged : default(DateTime?),
            LastName = user.LastName,
            UserId = user.UserId,
            EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress,
            Approved = user.Approved,
            UserType = UserType.ParseFromValue(user.UserTypeId)
        });
    }

    return users;
}
```

User class:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UserLoginLog = new List<UserLoginLog>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public List<UserLoginLog> UserLoginLog { get; set; }
}
```

UserLoginLog class

```
public class UserLoginLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateLogged { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try using Include: `context.User.Include(u => u.UserLoginLog).Where(query).Skip(skip).Take(count)`.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Coming from a LinqToSql background some things like this are easy to miss.